# How do CAD applications handle out-of-range characters in SHX fonts?

Tags: fonts, decimal, autocad, cad, bricscad

SHX fonts, commonly used in CAD applications, are compiled from SHP fonts. SHP fonts define character shapes for non-standard or extended ASCII characters `(0 to 255 decimal, or 0x0000 to 0x00FF in hexadecimal)`.

However, CAD applications often encounter text strings containing characters outside this range. In such cases, the application substitutes these "out-of-range" characters with alternative shapes for proper display.

For example, consider the text string `"fڑ©ha‌Œ"`. In decimal form, this translates to `"102 1681 169 104 97 8204 338"`. Characters `1681 (ڑ)`, `8204 (‌)`, `and 338 (Œ)` are outside the standard SHP font range ( `0 to 255 for most SHX fonts`).

Here's the key point: CAD applications like AutoCAD, Microstation, and BricsCAD remap these out-of-range characters to different shapes within the font's capabilities. In this example, they might be remapped to characters `154 (9A)`, `157 (9D)`, and `140 (8C)` respectively.

So, whether you input the original string `"fڑ©ha‌Œ"` or the string with remapped characters `"fšª™aŒ"` (using the decimal equivalents after remapping), the displayed output in the CAD application will be identical (as shown in the figure below).

[image]

**Question**:

How do CAD applications perform this remapping of out-of-range characters in SHX fonts? Is it folding, remapping, or a different process?
Does the SHP to SHX compilation process play any role in handling out-of-range characters?